# Not render a chip in multi value react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I don't want the chips to render in the multi value react-select. I want to do something else on selecting an option. How can I remove the chip rendering?

I tried setting controlShouldRenderValue={false} and that works. The chip is not added for any option selected. 
But I want to add a chip for certain options and not add a chip for certain options. Is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code which you have tried and didn't work so that we can take a look at your code and correct you or help you  with the fix

Comment: If you're using V2 I suggest you take a look at [Replacing components](https://react-select.com/components#replacing-components). I've achieved replacing the chips for a counter of the selected items by using a custom  `ValueContainer` but it's difficult to provide a full answer with so little information about what you want and have tried